# (DJANGO) How to set current.username in author comment section

Tags: django, django-models

I have `Comment` model in my Django app.

I want to make comment author to be current registered `author`, not another registered account.

Here is screenshot, I can choose `user2` account to post the comment, but currently I'm on `user1` account.[image]

Here is my Django `Comment` model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

And some code from html form:

```
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      <!-- comments -->
      {% if comments.count == 1 %}
        <h2>{{ comments.count }} comment</h2>
      {% else %}
        <h2>{{ comments.count }} comments</h2>
      {% endif %}

      {% for comment in comments %}
      <div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">
          {{ comment.name }}
          <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
            {{ comment.created_on }}
          </span>
        </p>
        {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% if new_comment %}
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Your comment is awaiting moderation
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
      {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
      <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
        {{ comment_form | crispy }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </article>
```

**EDIT**

view.py

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'posts': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the field non-editable, by setting the [**`editable=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable) to `False`. I furthermore advise to use `user` and *not* `name`, since it is a reference to the user object, not the name of the user:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.user)
```

Then in your view, when the form is valid, you set the `instance.user` of that form to the `request.user`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_comment(request, post_id):
    # …
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            # …
        # …
    # …
```

Comment: ```raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (name) specified for Comment```

Something with ```editable=False```

Comment: @CODE: well if you rename a field, then of course you need to rename all uses of that field. So maybe you should first test this before renaming the field (and thus first use `form.instance.name = request.user`) :)

Comment: @WilliemVanOnsem Ok, will try, but I've already renamed ```name`` to ```user```, and it didn't work. Will reply in 3 min

Comment: @CODE: the point is not renaming the field, the point is that if you rename a field, you need to rewrite all *uses* of that field.

Comment: Another error, seems it's something with editable method: ```django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'name' cannot be specified for Comment model form as it is a non-editable field```

Comment: @CODE: well evidently you should remove the `'name'` from the `fields` of your form.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there shouldn't be a choice of users. To identify user just use `request.user` in your view. I don't know how your view looks like, but you can set `name` like this:

```
name = request.user
# or if you're using classes:
name = self.request.user
```

Comment: See **EDIT**, I have added view.py

Comment: Didn't work for me, I tried to add ```author = self.request.author``` after ```if comment_form.is_valid():```. In **models.py** I renamed ```name``` into author.
Need ur help